# Popup object not working when gave as parameter of KeyAdapter

Tags: java, swing, popup, listener, keylistener

I want to show a Popup under a JTexField once a key is pressed. The idea is a Popup showing a JList inside a JScrollPane. The JList will provide suggestions to autocomplete the JTextField text, with Strings previously stored in a database. So I write a KeyAdapter to listen the keys and included a Popup object as a parameter. That Popup object was already declared. The problem is that the Popup never showed up. What am I doing wrong?

Minimal and reproducible code:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    private JTextField myTextField;
    private Popup myPopup;
    private PopupFactory myPopupFactory;
    private JList<String> myList;
    private JScrollPane myScrollPane;

    public Main() {

        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        myList = new JList<String>();

        myScrollPane = new JScrollPane(myList, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        myPopupFactory = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
        myPopup = myPopupFactory.getPopup(this.getContentPane(), myScrollPane, this.getLocation().x,
                this.getLocation().y);

        myTextField = new JTextField();
        myTextField.addKeyListener(new keyPres(myPopup));

        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(this.getContentPane());
        gl.setHorizontalGroup(
                gl.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap(40, 40).addComponent(myTextField, 200, 200, 200));
        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap(10, 10).addComponent(myTextField, 25, 25, 25));
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(gl);
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main main = new Main();
        main.setVisible(true);

    }

    private class keyPres extends KeyAdapter {
        private Popup myPop;

        public keyPres(Popup p) {
            this.myPop = p;
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (!(((JTextField) e.getSource()).getText().equals(""))) {
                this.myPop.show();
            } else {
                this.myPop.hide();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If I not set a Popup parameter and declare the Popup inside the KeyAdapter, show() method works but hide() not. If and else statements work fine, I tested with console prints.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`.

Comment: Maybe use the `setComponentPopupMenu(...)`. It will use the LAF key bindings to display the popup.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank you! I edited the question. Now it have minimal code, the same problem and is reproducible. I also make clearer what I expect to do with this piece of code. Therefore, I think that key bindings may not be the answer. camickr, I do not know if PopupMenu can handle dozens of items, I will look for it! Maybe that works!

Comment: @camickr it worked like a charm! Never had used JPopupMenu before! Actually, I am a beginner... Instead of adding a lot of JMenuItem rows, I just added my JScrollPane to a single JMenuItem. Thank you!